TypeError: create_lstm_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'optimizer'
def create_lstm_model(optimizer, neurons, activation):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=neurons, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

param_grid = {'neurons': [8, 16, 32, 64, 128],
              'optimizer': [SGD(), RMSprop(), Adam()],
              'activation': ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'linear','swish']
              }

model = KerasRegressor(model=create_lstm_model, neurons=8, activation='relu', epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, refit=False, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", n_jobs = -1, error_score='raise')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

In thie above code, I have the following error:
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-15-f5591384846f\> in \<cell line: 1\>()
130     model = KerasRegressor(model=create_lstm_model, neurons=8, activation='relu', epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)
131     grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, refit=False, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", n_jobs = -1, error_score='raise')
\--\> 132     grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
133
134     print("-- Evaluating --")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in \_return_or_raise(self)
761         try:
762             if self.status == TASK_ERROR:
\--\> 763                 raise self.\_result
764             return self.\_result
765         finally:

TypeError: create_lstm_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'optimizer'

I'm looking at the function create_lstm_model(), but I can't expect what's wrong.

You are not passing any optimizer which is the first input argument in your create_lstm_model() function.  Try this: model = KerasRegressor(model=create_lstm_model, optimizer = SGD(), neurons=8, activation='relu', epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

Explanation
The problem is that create_lstm_model requires 3 arguments: optimizer, neurons, and activation.  Your code above never calls create_lstm_model itself.  Instead, you pass the function create_lstm_model as an argument to the function (or constructor) KerasRegressor here:
model = KerasRegressor(model=create_lstm_model, neurons=8, activation='relu', epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

Code inside KerasRegressor actually calls the function create_lstm_model.  I don't have visibility in KerasRegressor to see what that code does.  However it's probably something like this:
    # could be this
    model (*args)
    # or maybe this
    model (neurons=neurons, activation=activation)

Fix
I see a few ways to fix it without modifying KerasRegressor code.
Option 1 might be to just pass an optimizer as a named param to KerasRegressor, if KerasRegressor just passes unknown params to the model.  However you'll have to pick one optimizer for it to use, instead of the 3 optimizers you have in param_grid:
opt = param_grid ['optimizer'] [0]  # selects SGD ()
model = KerasRegressor(model=create_lstm_model, neurons=8, activation='relu', optimizer=opt, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

Option 2: Pass a lambda function to KerasRegressor.  This only works if KerasRegressor calls your func with fixed args in fixed order (second example above).  Again you need to pick an optimizer first.
Your code becomes:
opt = param_grid ['optimizer'] [0]  # selects SGD ()
model = KerasRegressor(
    model = lambda neurons, activation : create_lstm_model (optim , neurons, activation), 
neurons=8, activation='relu', epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

Option 3 : use functools.partial to bind the optimizer arg to create_lstm_model and pass the result to KerasRegressor.  This should work regardless of argument order or style used in KerasRegressor.
Option 4 : rewrite create_lstm_model to remove the optimizer parameter.
Any of these require rethinking your approach a bit.  You may have to loop over the 3 different optimizers and run KerasRegressor / GridSearchCV separately on each one.
Hope this helps.
